# How to declare and add to a global array list?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, arguments

I have a project on entering an integer value into a global array. I'm using ArrayList and can't seem to figure out how to add values into the array I'm not quite sure how to add the integer to the array, as it is global and the actionPerformed function is local. Also, is where the array was declared considered correct?

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    int intEnter = Integer.parseInt(this.txtEnter.getText());
}                                      


public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList <Integer> intMarks = new ArrayList();
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MarksCalculator().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What about a class attribute?

Comment: If you care about being thread-safe for your global list : [Collections#synchronizedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the arraylist `intMarks` is not global, it is a local variable of the `main` method.
To make it a gobal variable you have to make it a direct variable of your class.

```
class ClassName{

    private static ArrayList <Integer> intMarks; 

    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        int intEnter = Integer.parseInt(this.txtEnter.getText());
        intMarks.add(intEnter);
    }                                      


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        intMarks = new ArrayList<>();
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MarksCalculator().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Further, you have to make the `intMarks` static to use it in the `main` method

Answer (score 1):

The array should be declared as static field of your class.

```
private static ArrayList <Integer> intMarks;

private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
   int intEnter = Integer.parseInt(this.txtEnter.getText());
   intMarks.add(intEnter);
}                                      


public static void main(String args[]) {
    intMarks = new ArrayList();
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MarksCalculator().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the arraylist is global then it could be accesses anywhere in any function of the same class. while you can add the values like mArrayListName.add(1);  i.e. for the int type arraylist

Answer (score 0):

You can use [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern.

```
public class Singleton {

private ArrayList<Object> arrayList;

private static Singleton instance;

private Singleton(){
    arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();
}

public static Singleton getInstance(){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new Singleton();
    }
return instance;
}

public ArrayList<Object> getArrayList() {
   return arrayList;
}
}
```

And you can add value in any class.

```
public class ExampleClass{
Singleton.getInstance().getArrayList().add(sampleObject);
}
```

*Note*: If you provide multithread processing, you can use [double check locking.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56232753/using-java-singleton-instance-in-a-multi-threaded-environment/56234127#56234127) Because ArrayList not thread safe.